# Matplotlib Multiple Combo-Charts with subplots and gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to merge(subplot) two combo-chart with the following code .
The problem is there is no ( or wrong ) lineplot for the first subplot (ax1 & ax2 ).
the left lineplot should look like the right one ( not equal ) .

row data is OK for all subplots , since when i plot them stand alone it works just fine.

what am i doing wrong here.

thanks

'''

```
#Create combo chart

fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2, hspace=0, wspace=0)
(ax1, ax3) = gs.subplots(sharex='col', sharey='row')

###########################################

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=25) 

ax1 = sns.barplot(x='STRT', y='Qnt', data = utw, ax = ax1,palette='summer',ci=None)

ax2 = plt.twinx()

ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='STRT', y='Yield', hue='Yield_m', data = utw,ax =ax1, sort=False, color=color,ci=None)

###########################################

ax3 = sns.barplot(x='STRT', y='Qnt', data = jbl, ax = ax3,palette='summer',ci=None)

#ax2=ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
ax4 = plt.twinx()

ax4 = sns.lineplot(x='STRT', y='Yield', hue='Yield_m', data = jbl,ax=ax4, sort=False, color=color,ci=None)
###########################
```

'''

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW560.png]

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Various data problems can lead to this output, so there is no use hypothesizing on all kinds of possible reasons for your incorrect output. Have you checked that your datetime objects are indeed datetime objects and not strings?

Comment: You seem to do `ax2 = sns.lineplot(...,ax=ax1)`. Maybe you meant to use `ax2` here: `sns.lineplot(...,ax=ax2)`?  (Also note that the code looks cleaner without assigning the result of `sns....` in case `ax=` is used as a parameter.)

Comment: Hi , thank you both for your help. i dont think this is "ax" issues , i have tried all possible combinations. I need to see some example for combo chart with grid_spec